# CSS Different screen resolution

Tags: html, css, web, resolution

I created a website with my resolution(1680x1050) and i uploaded to a free website and i sent the link to my friend have 1920x1080 resolution. My resolution in image 1, my friend is image 2, and the website.

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

And the website is: easyhost.atw.hu
If anybody can help me, very very thanks.

Comment: what help do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

1. i think you web site not structured very well this is the first
   point you should work on it
2. you must add a div named wrapper include all your content
3. you must use media queries on CSS for deferent resolution

> That's all you need to make your website perfect have fun

Comment: Can i edit my website to use with different resolution very simple?

Comment: yes if you do like i said you will reach your goal , also look at the Derek Baxter answer the foundation and bootstrap gonna help more on the resolution or you can use media queries like this  :                     @media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  .bloc {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

the best thing I would tell you is to download bootstrap or foundation that will make it a lot easier for you

http://getbootstrap.com/

http://foundation.zurb.com/

use their documentation to learn more about it. It is quite straight forward.